# How to optimize this SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Any other way to make this query faster cause it took about 5-7 minutes for the results to show.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.record = table2.col1 + ',' + table2.col2 
                  OR table1.record = table2.col1 + ',' + table2.col2 + ',' table2.col3
WHERE (CAST(table2.record AS DATE) >= CAST('03/01/2023' AS DATE) 
  AND (CAST(table2.record AS DATE) <= CAST('03/05/2023' AS DATE)
```

I already created an index but it didn't help much as its still slow

Comment: SQL is declarative i.e. is just a description of the results you want. **How** the engine obtains them is up to it, and to see how it does that you need to view the execution plan which will show you why its taking too long and then you can work out what to do about it. If you desire assistance with that you need to provide the execution plan using Paste The Plan.

Comment: Change your table design to a) get rid of the unnormalized CSV data, and b) store dates as proper dates, not text, so that the `WHERE` clause becomes sargable (i.e. can use an index).

Comment: (1) `WHERE date AS DATE >= @date AS DATE AND date AS DATE <= @date AS DATE` this seems like a really complicated way to do an equals, and (2) I'm pretty sure your index isn't going to be used on concatenated values.

Comment: edited my WHERE clause to what I used

Comment: In addition to the execution plan you need to provide table and index definitions else we are only guessing. But I am guessing you have stored your dates badly as strings which then means you have to do an entire table scan to perform your query.

Comment: You also want to ensure you use unambiguous date formats for your constant dates. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly

Comment: `OR`'s are also notoriously slow especially in a join with string concatenation which is going to require another table scan.

Comment: The `CAST(table2.record AS DATE)` is likely the performance killer. It eliminates any posibility of using an index on `table2.record` as the starting point of a query plan. Is `table2.record` of type `DATETIME`? If so, the trick will be to rewrite the condition to avoid teh cast.

Comment: @TN - SQL Server can often use a dynamic seek in this type of case. Which whilst not optimal can still use an index seek https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thank you for the info. I stand corrected. I ran a few tests and confirmed the dynamic seek behavior described in the linked article. That same article also indicates that the OR condition in the original query could also be handled with a dynamic seek, as long as the plan orders the joins as table2 join table1. (I guess I spent too much time working older servers that didn't have a true DATE type and folks used cast to varchar or float hacks to truncate dates. Those were the performance killers to be avoided.) Again thanks. I learned something today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '03/01/2023'
DECLARE @ThruDate DATETIME = '03/05/2023'

-- Calculate exclusive end date/time
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ThruDate)

SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.record = table2.col1 + ',' + table2.col2 OR
                     table1.record = table2.col1 + ',' + table2.col2 + ',' table2.col3
WHERE table2.record >= @FromDate AND
      table2.record < @ToDate -- Note the inequality
```

You will also need to ensure that you have an indexes on `table2(record)` and `table1(record)`

This defines start and end date/times that can be used to directly define the lookup range for `table2.record`. This should allow the query optimizer to efficiently perform a range seek on the `table2(record)` index.

After that, the optimizer might also be able to perform a loop join to the `table1(record)` index for each of the two values.  If it doesn't, you might need to rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        (table2.col1 + ',' + table2.col2),
        (table2.col1 + ',' + table2.col2 + ',' table2.col3)
) A(matchValue)
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.record = A.matchValue
WHERE table2.record >= @FromDate AND
      table2.record < @ToDate -- Note the inequality
```

(I certainly hope `record` is not your actual column names. Even if you are stripping the schema down for the purpose of the question, it is helpful if you still use names that have some relation to their meaning or usage.)

Comment: Thank you! the cross apply helped my query to search faster